# Install adwords api for python

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to install a library (Google adwords api) in python in Command Prompt. But when I ask:

```
setup.py install
```

Prompt opens the file steup.py in notepad and doesn't install the file.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: `python setup.py install`

Comment: This give me the following message: "python is not a recognized intern command"

Comment: Solved! I changed the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the Python's **installation path** into the environmental variables.